# How to use Unity.RegisterType with Moq?

Tags: unity-container, moq

I have a running code  with unity.

Now I want to use  Moq to do my unit testing for ASP-MVC. 
In the global.asax's code, I have the following:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>(new InjectionConstructor("xxx"));
```

Now I wrote testcode with Moq:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
var mockFoo = new Mock<IFoo>();
```

`container.RegisterType<IFoo, mockFoo) >(new InjectionConstructor("xxx"));`

but this don't work.

Error:
The type 'Moq.Mock' cannot be used as type parameter 'TTo' in the generic type or method 
'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterType...
There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Moq.Mock' to 'IFoo'

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are trying to register the mock-object, not the mocked-object.

```cs
var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
container.RegisterInstance<IFoo>(mock.Object);
```

Comment: Consider creating your Mock with MockBehavior.Strict so you know if you didn't implement a method that was used for your tests.          new Mock<IFoo>(MockBehavior.Strict);