# Moq with Unity Container unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-container, moq

below is an example of production code that I am trying to unit test. I am struggling to resolve a dependency to a concrete class that is being used.

```
public MyClass(IUnityContainer container)
{
    this.unityContainer = container;
}

public string DoWork()
{
     var sender = unityContainer.Resolve<IInterface>();  // how to setup this object
     var json = sender.Send("something");
     var value = serializer.Deserialize<SomeModel>(json);
     return value.url;
}
```

I want to mock out the IInterface used by this method. How do I set that up in my unit test code? I feel like there is something missing here. this has a smell of an anti-pattern.....

Comment: @CodeCaster It isnt my code :( just simply trying to increase our code coverage. I have no idea why they are passing an instance of the DI container into this class.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the ["service locator" antipattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/), where you inject your dependency injection container / inversion of control into your logic.

You should pass the `IInterface` that it depends on instead, so that you control what instances it can otain. See [Dependency Injection container in constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11389960/dependency-injection-container-in-constructor).

If you can't refactor the class, you have to injecting the container in your unit test. Set up the container to return an instance (or rather, a mock) of `IInterface`. Like this:

```
public void MyUnitTest()
{
    IUnityContainer myContainer = new UnityContainer();
    myContainer.RegisterType<IInterface, YourInstance>();

    MyClass classUnderTest = new MyClass(myContainer);
    classUnderTest.DoWork();
    
    Assert...
}
```

See [How to use Unity.RegisterType with Moq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614703/how-to-use-unity-registertype-with-moq) to mock the `YourInstance`.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with CodeCaster.  The typical pattern would be to accept a parameter of type *IInterface* in the constructor and assign it to a class-level variable.

```
public MyClass(IInterface sender)
{
    this.sender = sender;
}
```

When testing, simply pass in your moq.
That said, there are times when I dislike passing in a dependency through the constructor.  Such as:

- I may need multiple instances of a class
- The object is only needed conditionally.
- The class's constructor may depend on additional values that are not determined until run time.

In those cases, passing the container as a parameter is the only solution I've come across. Just be sure to register your initial instance of the container with itself.  Otherwise, the DI will provide your constructor with a new (empty) container. If anyone has a better pattern, particularly one that works with Unity, I'd love to see it.

Comment: Another option for just-in-time or multiple instances is to pass in a factory interface.  Then you call the factory zero or more times with on-the-fly parameters as needed (or not needed).